# Ruby equivalent of .irbrc?

Tags: ruby, irb

While `irb` utilizes `.irbrc` to automatically perform certain actions upon start, I have not been able to find how to do the same automatically for invocations of `ruby` itself. Any suggestions where the documentation for such can be found would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what the use case for this is.

Comment: The same use case behind `.irbrc` but applied to the running of ruby scripts instead.

Comment: Except it would apply to all Ruby scripts, even ones you didn't write… this could potentially have horrible ramifications for third-party applications.

Comment: While, theoretically, such is correct, the configuration and use of the given system does not pose such a risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For environments where I need this (essentially never) I've used the `-r [filename]` option, and the `RUBYOPT` environment variable.

*(You may want to specify include directories, which can be done a variety of ways, including the `-I [directory]` option).*

This is essentially the same answer as Phrogz, but without the shell script. The scripts are a bit more versatile since you can have any number of them for trivial pre-execution environment rigging.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can use `ruby -rfoo` to require library `foo` for that run, so you can specify to always require a particular library for every Ruby run:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.ruby/lib/mine.rb" ]; then
  RUBYLIB="$HOME/.ruby/lib"
  RUBYOPT="rmine"
  export RUBYLIB RUBYOPT
fi
```

Put your own custom code in a file (like `mine.rb` above) and get your interpreter to always add its directory to your `$LOAD_PATH` (aka `$:`) and always `require` it (which runs the code therein).

Shell code above and background information here:
http://tbaggery.com/2007/02/11/auto-loading-ruby-code.html